# Wait() in process creation

Tags: c++, gcc, wait

The following is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {
         int cpid=fork();

         if(cpid==0) {
                printf("%d %d\n",getpid(),getppid());  
         }
         else {
                printf("hello");
                wait(NULL);
         }
 }
```

When I compile this using the following:

```
g++ -std=c++11 multiple.cpp -o multiple
It gives me the following

multiple.cpp: In function 'int main()':
multiple.cpp:34:23: error: no matching function for call to 'wait::wait(NULL)'
              wait(NULL);
                       ^
multiple.cpp:34:23: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:42:0,
                 from multiple.cpp:4:
/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h:66:7: note: wait::wait()
 union wait

/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h:66:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h:66:7: note: constexpr wait::wait(const wait&)
/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h:66:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const wait&'
/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h:66:7: note: constexpr wait::wait(wait&&)
/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h:66:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'wait&&'
```

But if I change the extension to `.c` and use `gcc -o multiple multiple.c` it works. Why is this happening?

Comment: You probably are missing the Linux or POSIX tags

Comment: RTFM [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html)

Answer (score 3):

You have not included the correct header file that the  [wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html)() documentation tells you need.

You need

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because wait is declared in sys/wait.h, which you do not include, and C++ requires all the functions to be prototyped before used. C, on the other hand, does not.

Comment: You do not know that it is "wrong". It's a perfectly valid and compliant scenario. That being said, your rationale is far more likely. :)

Answer (score 2):

You did not include the header for the POSIX `wait` function, per [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html):

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

It is surprising but not inconceivable that the equivalent standard library headers in your C toolchain just so happen to include this themselves, whereas the C++ ones you have used do not.

More likely, you are inadvertently making use of the terrible rule in C that says you can use some functions before they have been declared.

Comment: Thanks it worked.But why is it different for C and C++.

Comment: @AdityaSharma You can't call a function in C++ without a prototype for it, while in C  you can.